# intercept form submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to intercept a submit via jQuery and first check if a file is present on the server. If it's present continue with the request, if not display a message and don't send the request. This is what I have:

```
$("#methodForm").submit(function(e){

    checkIndex('upload/segments.gen').done(function() {
        return true;
    }).fail(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("No index present!");
        return false;
    });
});
```

this is the `checkIndex()`:

```
function checkIndex(file){
    return $.ajax({
        url : file,
        type:'HEAD'
    });
}
```

What happens is this: The file is present on the server, but the `checkIndex` returns with fail. First I see the alert popup and then it continues and sends the post request to the server.

I use the `checkIndex()` for other purposes as well where it works like expected so I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere in the submit routine. But I can't find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will only work with synchronous AJAX request. You should disable the button and enable it on `done` callback

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can't return out of a callback to an asynchronous method(such as ajax). Instead, prevent the submit all together, then submit it when you are ready.

```
$("#methodForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    checkIndex('upload/segments.gen').done(function() {
        form.submit(); // submit bypassing the jQuery bound event
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("No index present!");
    });
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with one further twist: A dialog displaying the images to be overwritten is shown. A click on the "Confirm" button (`<a>` element) would submit the form. I had to make sure to add `e.preventDefault()` when handling that click event, otherwise my request would be blocked.

Answer (score 3):

It does'nt really work like that, checkIndex is asynchronous, so by the time it returns anything, the form is submitted, and the return statements are in a different scope as well, try something more like this:

```
$("#methodForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
    var self = this;
    checkIndex('upload/segments.gen').done(function() {
        self.submit(); //submit if ajax OK
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("No index present!");
   });
});
```